# Dealing with Async operations in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous

In my service, I am consuming the Http service from the HttpModule. I am using http.get() method to fetch JSON response from an API. The `http.get()` method returns an Observable.I am subscribing to this Observable in my Component.

In the same service, there is another http.get() method that fetches data from another API. Again, I am subscribing to this Observable in my component.

I want to use the values provided by these two methods, perform some calculation and then render the answer to my HTML page. However, as the operations are asynchronous, I cannot perform calculations in the component because it gives me an undefined answer. So, I have to perform calculations on my HMTL page. I don't want to do it this, way because I am using the same service in different components and I am repeating my code multiple times.

Is there a better way to do so?

This is the method I use in my service

```
getAnswer() {
    return this.http.get(this.url1)
    .map(res => res.json());
}

getAnotherAnswer() {
    return this.http.get(this.url2)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

This is my component

```
Service.getAnswer().subscribe(res=>{
  this.ans1= res;
});

Service.getAnotherAnswer().subscribe(res=>{
  this.ans2= res;
});
```

Suppose I get two number from the API and I want to add the two numbers, I have to do so in my HTML

```
<h3> {{ ans1 + ans2 }}</h3>
```

I want this calculation in my Component, but I cannot because these values are asynchronous and when I try to add them, I get an undefined answer.

How, do I add these values in my component?

Comment: 1. Don't use the deprecated Http module. Use HttpClient, as documented: https://angular.io/guide/http 2. Use the forkJoin method: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use observable operators

```
Observable.zip(Service.getAnswer(), Service.getAnotherAnswer()).first().subscribe(res =>{
  [this.ans1, this.ans2] = res;
  // or you can do calculation here and write it to a single variable
  // to show it in template
});
```

btw, if you have rxjs 5.5+ you can write it in better way to keep rxjs size smaller inside of bundle